# Set User as audience of Navigation Link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, audiences

Is it possible to add single users as an audience to a navigation link?

From everything that I've been able to find on the subject, this doesn't seem possible.

Right now I have a rule for one of my audiences which the following - Work Email contains @domain.

This only brings up all of the members of the compiled audience.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SharePoint group, add individual users to that group and then use that group in the audience settings of the navigation link.

I often use that approach to give only a handful of people access to specific aspects of a site via navigation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion teylyn.  While I do have a number of SharePoint groups, and Audiences aren't a way of making a specific link fully secure from others being able to access it, I'm still looking to see if a single user can be added as an audience to a navigation link.